# Como evitar a exclusão de dados relacionais através de integridade referencial no MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Tenho as tabelas SIMULADO e QUESTAO, onde um simulado pode ter várias questões, mas uma questão só pode ser para um simulado (relacionamento 1-n).

**TABELA SIMULADO:**

```
simuladoId
simuladoNome
```

**TABELA QUESTAO**

```
questaoId
questaoPergunta
questaoIdSimulado
```

Gostaria de saber como evitar que esses dados relacionais fossem apagados. Ou seja, quando eu deletar um simulado que tenha sua chave estrangeira propagada para uma ou mais questão, fosse emitido um erro, impedindo.

Pelo pouco que pesquisei entendi que, pelo menos no MYSQL, é possível através de Triggers.. Mas pouco entendo do assunto, então gostaria de alguma outra opção, ou até mesmo alguns exemplos de trigger.

Eu tentei o seguinte:

```
alter table ang_questao add constraint FK_ang_questao foreign key (questao_id_simulado) references ang_simulado (simulado_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

Executei e não foi exibido erro algum no SQL.

Quando tentei apagar, foi-me exibido:

> Erro ao Deletar: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451
>   Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`simulado_anglo`.`ang_questao`, CONSTRAINT `FK_ang_questao` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`questao_simulado_id`) REFERENCES `ang_simulado` (`simulado_id`))
>
> Erro na Linha: #10 :: Cannot modify header information - headers
>   already sent by (output started at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\simulado-geral\config.php:33)
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\simulado-geral\admin\php\deletar.php

Comment: Thiago, você quer REALMENTE DELETAR, ou impedit que fosse deletado? No caso de chaves estrangeiras em outras tabelas, como no caso você tem um Simulado de 10 questões, porém quando vai deletar da este erro, o jeito é você através de trigger remover a chave estrangeira das questões onde era o ID dele colocar NULL ou direcionar para outro simulado, ou uma trigger deletando as questões primeiro para depois deletar o questionário OU na hora de criar a tabela coloca o ON DELETE CASCADE na foreign key. Que ai quando deletar o simulado as questões são deletadas.

Comment: Eu quero saber como ficaria caso eu quisesse as duas opções: Quando deletar um simulado, remover em modo cascata as questões referentes, ou então não permitir que o simulado fosse apagado.

Comment: Você pode dar um SHOW TRIGGERS no console. Cara dependendo da utilização do simulado ao invés de você deletar REALMENTE do banco você pode criar uma coluna no simulado dar o update de ativo e inativo, é uma dica. Mas ai no caso para setar o on delete cascade da uma olhada por aqui http://stackoverflow.com/a/18616544/6405917 que é isso.

Comment: Realmente seria muito mais viável uma coluna de status, até porque se for pensar a logo prazo, seria possível a reutilização do mesmo.. Obrigado pela dica! E referente a trigger, eu consegui dando uma lida no link. Obrigado.

Comment: Sim se for pensar por este lado é interessante para reaproveitamento ao invés do delete mesmo dos dados. É como se fosse a conta do facebook. Existe lá a tabela de CONTA e não é permitido o delete da conta na sua totalidade, apenas a desabilitação, caso queira o delete mesmo tem que enviar email e tal pra lá e tem toda uma burocracia por causa dos dados. Serve informação também valeu.

Comment: @GustavoTinoco, Deixei com RESTRIC, e agora ficou da seguinte forma: Quando eu TENTO apagar uma questão é exibido o mesmo erro. A ideia da lógica deveria ser a seguinte: Ao apagar um simulado que contenha questões, dê erro. Porém, ao apagar uma questão, tudo bem.. Até porque uma questão depende de um simulado, mas o mesmo não depende de uma questão.

Comment: Assim como o @GustavoTinoco, eu incentivo a criação de uma coluna de statusativo ou inativo, assim fica melhor pra gerenciar, dá pra reutilizar questões e se você estiver mexendo com programação num geral e não apenas banco de dados, tem como na sua aplicação fazer  uma pagina de gerenciamento das questões inativas, para poder edita-las e o que mais precisar.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde Thiago,

*Eu quero saber como ficaria caso eu quisesse as duas opções: Quando deletar um simulado, remover em modo cascata as questões referentes, ou então não permitir que o simulado fosse apagado.*

1) Para quando excluir um Simulado excluir em cascata as Questões, você deve utilizar "on delete cascade" na constraint Foreign Key.

2) Para não permitir que o Simulado seja excluído possuindo pelo menos uma Questão, você já fez isso ao criar a constraint de Foreign Key normalmente.

Meu Exemplo:

1) Cria as tabelas:

```
mysql> create table simulado
-> (simuladoId int not null auto_increment,
->  simuladoNome varchar(40) not null,
->  primary key (simuladoId)
-> ) engine=innodb;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (1,25 sec)

mysql> create table questao
    -> (questaoId int not null auto_increment,
    ->  questaoPergunta varchar(40) not null,
    ->  questaoIdSimulado int not null,
    ->  primary key (questaoId),
    ->  constraint fk_questao_questaoIdSimulado foreign key (questaoIdSimulado) references simulado (simuladoId)
    -> ) engine=innodb;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,57 sec)
```

2) Insere os registros:

```
mysql> insert into simulado values (1, 'Simulado do Fernando');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,06 sec)

mysql> insert into questao values (1, 'Pergunta 1', 1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,02 sec)

mysql> insert into questao values (2, 'Pergunta 2', 1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,07 sec)
```

3) Agora tenta excluir o Simulado, não vai deixar:

```
mysql> delete from simulado where simuladoId=1;
ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`teste`.`questao`, CONSTRAINT `fk_questao_questaoIdSimulado` FOREIGN KEY (`questaoIdSimulado`) REFERENCES `simulado` (`simuladoId`))
```

4) Se quero excluir os registros-filhos do Simulado, devo alterar a constraint na tabela-filha (Questao) para deleção em cascata, exemplo:

```
mysql> alter table questao drop foreign key fk_questao_questaoIdSimulado;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,52 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> alter table questao add constraint fk_questao_questaoIdSimulado 
    -> foreign key (questaoIdSimulado) references 
    -> simulado (simuladoId) on delete cascade;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (1,08 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

5) Agora ao excluir o registro-pai do Simulado exclui automaticamente os registros-filhos de Questões:

```
mysql> delete from simulado where simuladoId=1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,02 sec)

mysql> select * from simulado;
Empty set (0,00 sec)

mysql> select * from questao;
Empty set (0,01 sec)
```