# Verificar se chave estrangeira esta sendo usada

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho 2 tabelas:

Funcionario

- idFuncionario
- Nome
- Endereco
- profissao

Profissao

- idProfissao
- nomeProfissao

Sendo que profissao da tabela funcionario é uma chave estrangeira de idProfissão da tabela Profissao.

Queria um código PHP que verificasse se a chave estrangeira esta sendo usada, para que eu possa bloquear sua exclusão.

Comment: O correto é no próprio banco você fazer essa tratativa se a tabela depende de outras. Mas o que pode fazer é um `select` de todos `id` da tabela, com um `where` do `id` que você quer saber se está sendo usado, o que não é uma boa prática, mas cada caso é um caso.

Comment: O próprio MYSQL já cuida disso.

Comment: A ideia seria você trazer um código e nos explicar a sua dúvida/dificuldade para lhe ajudarmos. O qual não é o caso solicitado. De todo e qualquer modo, uma chave estrangeira (quando criada) restringe a exclusão do registro, caso ele possuir uma referência em outra tabela.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152775/como-evitar-a-exclus%C3%A3o-de-dados-relacionais-atrav%C3%A9s-de-integridade-referencial-n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como comentei, o próprio banco de dados (no exemplo, MySQL) impossibilita essa exclusão. Segue uma print do Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O erro que é exibido:

> 16:39:29  DELETE FROM tbprofissao WHERE id = 3    Error Code: 1451. Cannot
>   delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`wrock`.`tbfuncionario`, CONSTRAINT `tbfuncionario_ibfk_1` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`profissao`) REFERENCES `tbprofissao` (`id`))    0.328 sec

*Edit (Após Comentário):*

Então, faça o seguinte (o 3 é o id desejado):

```
DELETE FROM tbprofissao WHERE tbprofissao.id NOT EXISTS ( SELECT tbfuncionario.profissao FROM tbfuncionario WHERE tbfuncionario.profissao = 3);
```

O que esse SQL faz ?
R: Ele vai deletar a linha da tabela tbprofissao que não exista na tabela funcionario

Comment: No meu exclui as duas tabelas
Mais acho que é porque coloquei casacade no ondelete

Comment: Olha a alteração

Comment: Eu vi. Só não vou conseguir alterar agora.

Mais assim que conseguir faço um feedback

Comment: Para o que eu precisava, só mudei de cascade para restrict e funcionou
Mais sua solução funciona sim.
Obrigado.

Comment: Caso esteja solucionado, marque como solucionado :)